# PhpStorm Segmentation fault: 11 while run xdebug

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I have xdebug with PhpStorm 10  and got Segmentation fault: 11 whilt move between files in php.

for example:

```
file 1 : function 1 - enter from file 2 function call 
go back to file 2.php
call to another function in file 1 -> got error Segmentation fault: 11
```

the application works perfect without error , only in debug is crushed

Comment: Who reports "Segmentation fault": PhpStorm or PHP/xdebug?

Comment: @LazyOne hi . - the console while I run from the consol a php script

Comment: So .. it's a problem (extremely likely) with PHP itself. I suggest to reinstall your PHP -- update it; update xdebug and other modules etc.

Comment: Does it happen if you simply run the PHP scripts in the console?